# Google Earth Engine with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-earth-engine, geemap

I want to transfer to Google Earth Engine satellite images without downloading to Jupyter Notebook. Namely, I want for process in Jupyter Notebook of Google Earth Engine images brought to screen. I tried some solution paths but I can't.
Can you help me please?
Thank you.

My output image from GEE;

```py
>>> print(type(image4))
<class 'ee.image.Image'>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by brought to screen you mean displayed in Jupyter Notebooks, you can use Geemap.

```
import geemap

Map=geemap.Map()
Map.addLayer(image4, {}, 'image name')
Map
```

n.b. {} can be a dictionary of visualization parameters for your image.

The image will be displayed in Jupyter but will still be held on the cloud and will not be downloaded.

If you follow the geemap tutorials you can process the image and again display it in this way without downloading it. https://geemap.org/tutorials/